# How to scale a group of polygons proportionally to each other

Tags: geometry, polygons, ratio

I have a number of polygons which I want to scale between two limits, let's say 0 and 1 for simplicity. The polygons can have different shapes and areas. Always for the sake of simplification, we can take them as bounding boxes, so they're all rectangles.

[image]

I'd like to limit the scale of each polygon in relation to the others. As an example, I go on rescaling each poly in the picture from 0 to 1. Now the first poly in the picture is going to increase less than, say, the fourth one which, being the smallest, will incur the biggest scaling.
I want rect 4 to increase no more than rect 1 increase, or which is the least among all them. Hence my question:

How do I calculate a common ratio that allows me to control the scaling of this group of polys, so they mantain the same scaling increase proportion, irrespective of their number and sizes?

In short I want polys to scale limited to the lowest proportional increase, so if poly1 scales 2x and poly4 scales 4x, I want poly4 to scale 2x only.
Thank you

Comment: Is it a real problem to use the smallest of the scales ? (Which is just the inverse of the largest side among all polygons.)

Comment: ... so in your diagram the longest side seems to be $0.75$ (though the third diagram the vertical side might be larger) so you scale everything by $\frac43$?